# Using javascript to list hyperlink URL's as footnotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a print stylesheet, and I would like to put a numbered superscript next to each hyperlink with a footnote at the bottom of the page with the URL. This would make for a much cleaner printed page while still allowing you to view the hyperlinked URL's.

My needs are :

- Insert superscript of a number in numerical order where the hyperlink appears
- Take into account repeating URL's (if same URL appears twice, reuse the number)
- Specify a parent element ID to use (don't automatically do the entire page)

Here would be an example:

```
<p>I may link to <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>, 
then to <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>, then to 
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google again</a>. Then finally, 
I'll throw in <a href="http://www.bing.com">Bing</a> just for kicks.</p>
```

So, the Javascript should change this to display as:

---

I may link to Google<sup>1</sup>, then to Yahoo<sup>2</sup>, then to Google again<sup>1</sup>. Then finally, I'll throw in Bing<sup>3</sup> just for kicks.

LINKS:

1. http://www.google.com
2. http://www.yahoo.com
3. http://www.bing.com

---

I found some old Javascript snippet from 2005 on [this site](http://alistapart.com/article/improvingprint), but it seems horribly outdated and cumbersome.

```
function footnoteLinks(containerID,targetID) {
    if (!document.getElementById || 
        !document.getElementsByTagName ||
        !document.createElement) return false;
    if (!document.getElementById(containerID) ||
        !document.getElementById(targetID)) return false;
    var container = document.getElementById(containerID);
    var target    = document.getElementById(targetID);
    var h2        = document.createElement('h2');
    addClass.apply(h2,['print-onlyX']);
    var h2_txt    = document.createTextNode('Links');
    h2.appendChild(h2_txt);
    var coll = container.getElementsByTagName('*');
    var ol   = document.createElement('ol');
    addClass.apply(ol,['print-onlyX']);
    var myArr = [];
    var thisLink;
    var num = 1;
    for (var i=0; i<coll.length; i++) {
      var thisClass = coll[i].className;
      if ( coll[i].getAttribute('href') ||
           coll[i].getAttribute('cite') ) { 
        thisLink = coll[i].getAttribute('href') ? coll[i].href : coll[i].cite;
        var note = document.createElement('sup');
        addClass.apply(note,['print-onlyX color-light']);
        var note_txt;
        var j = inArray.apply(myArr,[thisLink]);
        if ( j || j===0 ) {
          note_txt = document.createTextNode(j+1);
        } else {
          var li     = document.createElement('li');
          var li_txt = document.createTextNode(thisLink);
          li.appendChild(li_txt);
          ol.appendChild(li);
          myArr.push(thisLink);
          note_txt = document.createTextNode(num);
          num++;
        }
        note.appendChild(note_txt);
        if (coll[i].tagName.toLowerCase() == 'blockquote') {
          var lastChild = lastChildContainingText.apply(coll[i]);
          lastChild.appendChild(note);
        } else {
          coll[i].parentNode.insertBefore(note, coll[i].nextSibling);
        }
      }
    }
    target.appendChild(h2);
    target.appendChild(ol);
    addClass.apply(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0],['noted']);
    return true;
  }
  window.onload = function() {
    footnoteLinks('content-main','content-main');
  }


  if(Array.prototype.push == null) {
    Array.prototype.push = function(item) {
      this[this.length] = item;
      return this.length;
    };
  };

  if (!Function.prototype.apply) {
    Function.prototype.apply = function(oScope, args) {
      var sarg = [];
      var rtrn, call;
      if (!oScope) oScope = window;
      if (!args) args = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        sarg[i] = "args["+i+"]";
      };
      call = "oScope.__applyTemp__(" + sarg.join(",") + ");";
      oScope.__applyTemp__ = this;
      rtrn = eval(call);
      oScope.__applyTemp__ = null;
    return rtrn;
    };
  };
  function inArray(needle) {
    for (var i=0; i < this.length; i++) {
      if (this[i] === needle) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
  function addClass(theClass) {
    if (this.className != '') {
      this.className += ' ' + theClass;
    } else {
      this.className = theClass;
    }
  }
  function lastChildContainingText() {
    var testChild = this.lastChild;
    var contentCntnr = ['p','li','dd'];
    while (testChild.nodeType != 1) {
      testChild = testChild.previousSibling;
    } 
    var tag = testChild.tagName.toLowerCase();
    var tagInArr = inArray.apply(contentCntnr, [tag]);
    if (!tagInArr && tagInArr!==0) {
      testChild = lastChildContainingText.apply(testChild);
    }
    return testChild;
  }
```

Is there a cleaner method of doing this? Seems like a lot of that old Javascript can be reduced by using jQuery.

Comment: What's native jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/onru1oL6/).

```js
(function($) {

  // init link's hash map
  var links = {};

  // init function named format
  // this method will format all a elements in $contianer
  var format = function($container) {
    // sup started by 1
    var index = 1;
    $container.find('a').each(function() {
      // href is map key, sup index is value
      links[$(this).attr('href')] = links[$(this).attr('href')] || index++;

      // replace the a tag inline with text and sup
      $(this).replaceWith($(this).text() + '<sup>' + links[$(this).attr('href')] + '</sup>');
    });

    // create link list
    var $list = $('<ol></ol>');
    Object.keys(links).forEach(function(link) {
      // append each link to this list
      $list.append('<li><a href="' + link + '">' + link + '</a></li>');
    })

    // append this list to $container
    $container.append($list);
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    // call this function
    format($('#result'));
  });
})(jQuery)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  I may link to <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>, then to <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>, then to <a href="http://www.google.com">Google again</a>. Then finally, I'll throw in <a href="http://www.bing.com">Bing</a> just for kicks.
</p>

<div id="result">
  <p>
    I may link to <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>, then to <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>, then to <a href="http://www.google.com">Google again</a>. Then finally, I'll throw in <a href="http://www.bing.com">Bing</a> just for kicks.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Looks great! I was just wondering if the line `var $list = $('<ol><ol>');` was correct because I did not see a closing `</ol>` tag...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to target all your `<a>` tags inside the parent element `<div id="parent">`, and you already have an element on the bottom of the page reserved for the links (say `<ul id="links">`), try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //get the array of all link tags
    var links = $('#parent a');

    //filter out duplicates
    var unique_links = [];
    $.each(links, function(i, el){
        if($.inArray(el, unique_links ) === -1) unique_links.push(el);
    });

    //loop through each element, first adding the link to the bottom and then adding the superscript
    for(i=0; i < unique_links.length; i++) {
        $('#links').append('<li>'+i+1+': '+unique_links[i].attr('href')+'</li>');
        unique_links[i].html(unique_links[i].text() + '<sup>'+i+1+'</sup>');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATED]: Complete solution using jQuery.

See jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Le1Lkcft/4/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var cpt = 0;
var arrLink = new Array();
$(document).ready(function(){
  function createFootnotes(){
    $('a').each(function(){
        var text = $(this).text();
        $link = $(this).prop('href');
        var found = arrLink.indexOf($link);
        if (found == -1){
            arrLink.push($link);
            cpt = arrLink.length;
        }else{
            cpt = parseInt(found)+1;
        }
        var $sup = '<sup>' + cpt + '</sup>';
        $(this).after($sup).before(text).remove();
        if (found == -1) $('body').append($sup + ' ' + $link + '<br>');
    });
}
$('#create').click(function(){
    createFootnotes();
});
});
</script>
```

And the HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="create" value="CREATE FOOTNOTES" /><hr>
<p>I may link to <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>, 
then to <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>. Then finally, 
I'll throw in <a href="http://www.bing.com">Bing</a> just for kicks,
then to <a href="http://www.google.com">Google again</a>.</p>
<p>So, therefore, whatever with a link to <a href="http://www.learnquebec.ca">LEARN</a> here, I say. Ah darn, <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a> again? No way!!!</p>
<hr>
```

Comment: That looks great, thank you for posting. The only problem is with reoccurring links repeating each other. The Google link in the example should only show once. There's no need to list the same URL more than once. Is there any way this could be updated for that?

Comment: Then feed a javascript array with the links, and look up the array for each new link in the EACH() loop. If found, add the superscript key to the html without adding the footnote.

Answer (score 0):

[image]I would just loop through your a link turn them to text and add the number and then append them to your footer or wherever you want.

```
$('a').each(function(i,v){
var $Aelement = $(this);
var $text = $Aelement.text();
var $link =$Aelement.attr('href');
var j = i+1;
$Aelement.replaceWith($text + '<sup><a href="#FN'+ j +'" id="ref' + j +'">'+j+'</a></sup>');
$('.footer').append('<sup id="fn'+ j +'">'+j+'. ['+$link+']<a href="#ref'+j+'" title="Jump back to footnote '+j+' in the text.">↩</a></sup><br />')
});
```

so the final product will look like something like this.

```js
$('a').each(function(i, v) {
  var $Aelement = $(this);
  var $text = $Aelement.text();
  var $link = $Aelement.attr('href');
  var j = i + 1;
  $Aelement.replaceWith($text + '<sup><a href="#FN' + j + '" id="ref' + j + '">' + j + '</a></sup>');
  $('.footer').append('<sup id="fn' + j + '">' + j + '. [' + $link + ']<a href="#ref' + j + '" title="Jump back to footnote ' + j + ' in the text.">↩</a></sup><br />')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>I may link to <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>, then to <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>, then to
  <a href="http://www.google.com">Google again</a>. Then finally, I'll throw in <a href="http://www.bing.com">Bing</a> just for kicks.</p>
<div class='footer'>

</div>
```

You can obviously play with the html and make it look different :)

Answer (score 0):

My version based on standard javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getLinks() {
            var lnks = document.getElementById('content').getElementsByTagName('a');
            var footLnks = [];
            var j = 1;
            for (var i = 0, ank; ank=lnks[i]; ++i) {
                footLnks[ank.href] = (footLnks[ank.href] || j++);
                var sup = document.createElement('sup');
                sup.innerHTML = footLnks[ank.href];
                ank.appendChild(sup);
            }
            var ul = document.getElementById('footlink');
            for (var href in footLnks) {
                var li = document.createElement('li');
                li.innerHTML = footLnks[href] + ': ' + href;
                ul.appendChild(li);
            }
        }
        //now use it
        window.onbeforeprint = getLinks;
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="content">
        I may link to <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>,
        then to <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>, then to
        <a href="http://www.google.com">Google again</a>. Then finally,
        I'll throw in <a href="http://www.bing.com">Bing</a> just for kicks.
    </p>
    <ul id="footlink">
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```